# Crystal Report - export to html with separate file attached

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi

I have a question regarding developing crystal report.

One of our requirements, is to able send a dynamic crystal report email (depending on the report nature eg, Accounts Payable, AR) to their clients, then send the actual report in pdf attached to this html email. Any idea how to implement it?

sample crystal report email:

**Dear Client A (dynamic name),*

Attached on this email is your current Accounts Payable for the month of June 2025.

(attached Account Payable Report pdf here or anywhere in the email)*

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the Crystal Reports Runtime and your own application to do this.
But it sounds like you need out-of-the-box solution.

There are several 3rd-party Crystal Reports automation tools that can do this. Ken Hamady maintains a listing of 3rd-party tools [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#desktopsched).